# Need help recreating this node setup in the new node system

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, instances

[image: screenshot from a tutorial of Geometry Nodes using Linear Falloff]

I'm following a tutorial on how to make a reveal effect using instanced points but the attribute vector node has been removed, I'm unsure of what it should be replaced with.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using, and what version is being used in the tutorial?

Comment: @Joachim Im using the latest stable version of blender. If all else fails I'll just have to download the version he was using, i would like to learn how to recreate it in the latest build though. Heres the link to the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKDC5YE-26k I did see that question but its not specific to what im trying to do.

Comment: @Joachim That tutorial says "This tutorial is using Blender 2.93.0 Beta" so a couple of years old!

Comment: @JohnEason yeah... super annoying will just download 2.93.17

Comment: In Blender 3, most of the *Attribute Vector* nodes can be replaced by a *Vector Math* node + the node that represents the attribute. For example, the left one in the screenshot is a *Position* node + a *Vector Math (Subtract)* node. For the scaling, this works perfectly but for the translation, there is something wrong. The *Normal* you have to caption by *Capture Attribute*. But the scaling kinda does not look right... I guess my model is too big so the scale value does not fit.